# Getting "The server's host key is not cached in the registry" when using pscp.exe to transfer file from Windows to Unix server in VBA + Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sftp, putty

I have written VBA code on Excel. I'm trying to transfer a text file to my server by using SFTP and the file pscp.exe. The file will not be transferred and the window of pscp.exe will be displayed.

I will see the following message:

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You have no guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is. The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is: ssh-rsa XXXX XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting. If you want to carry on connecting just once, without adding the key to the cache, enter "n". If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the connection. Store key in cache? (y/n)

How could I solve my problem?

```
Dim Polku As String
Polku = "/"

Dim Palvelin As String
Palvelin = "grid1.example.xxx"

Dim Kayttajatunnus As String
Kayttajatunnus = "user@example.xxx"

Dim Salasana As String
Salasana = "Password2012"

Dim Tiedosto As String
Tiedosto = "filename.txt"

Dim PolkuOhjelma As String
Dim PolkuTiedosto As String

If Right$(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 1) <> "\" Then
    PolkuOhjelma = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\pscp.exe"
    PolkuTiedosto = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Tiedosto
Else
    PolkuOhjelma = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "pscp.exe"
    PolkuTiedosto = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Tiedosto
End If

Dim Siirtokomento As String
Siirtokomento = Chr$(34) & PolkuOhjelma & Chr$(34) & " -sftp -l " & Kayttajatunnus & _
    " -pw " & Salasana & " " & Chr$(34) & PolkuTiedosto & Chr$(34) & " " & _
    Palvelin & ":" & Polku

Debug.Print Siirtokomento

Shell Siirtokomento, vbNormalFocus
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) to explicitly specify a fingerprint of the trusted hostkey.

```
-hostkey XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```